# Long-term archiving + encrypting shell script

Tags: linux, aes, sh, posix, openssl

Yesterday, I very quickly, in an hour, wrote the very first version of my long-term archiving + encrypting shell script.

I am aware it may have too many flaws, but none of them really prevent it from normal operation, so before I take another step and restructure it with `printf` and better error reporting, structure, exit codes, etc. I would like you to have a look first.

What it does:

1. It archives a given directory into a tarball.
2. It compresses (with maximum effort) that tarball using `xz`.
3. It encrypts that `xz` archive using `openssl` and AES-256.
4. It creates and checks the created SHA-512 sum file.
5. It then decrypts the created file to a temporary file.
6. Finally, it compares the decrypted file with the original `xz` archive.

I am prepared to waste time and effort in order to be 100% sure before burning my precious data to Blu-ray M-disc.

I know I should not have to do steps 5 and 6 just because there is almost a 0% chance for the data to get corrupted in the process. But since I have a rather large NVMe SSD drive, and relatively fast CPU, it should not be so shocking that I wrote it with motto *better safe than sorry*.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -z "$1" ] && echo "You need to give me one directory!" && exit 1

[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "This is not a directory!" && exit 1

[ ! -w "$PWD" ] && echo "The current directory is not writable by you!" && exit 1

dir=$(basename "$1")
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

backupdir="${dir}_${today}"
# backupdir="${dir}"

backupfile="${backupdir}.tar"

bold=$(tput bold)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
nocolor=$(tput sgr0)
bold_red="$bold$red"
bold_yellow="$bold$yellow"

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}1/6: TAR is archiving your directory '${bold_red}$dir${bold_yellow}' into '${bold_red}$backupfile${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! tar -cf "$backupfile" "$1" --totals
then
    echo "TAR failed to archive your directory"
    exit 1
fi

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}2/6: XZ is compressing your '${bold_red}$backupfile${bold_yellow}' into '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! xz --format=xz --check=sha256 -9 --threads=8 --keep --verbose --verbose --extreme "$backupfile"
then
    echo "XZ failed to compress your backup file"
    exit 1
fi

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}3/6: OpenSSL is encrypting your '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz${bold_yellow}' into '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.enc${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! pv -W "$backupfile.xz" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "$backupfile.xz.enc" -pass file:/home/vlastimil/.blablablabla 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "OpenSSL failed to encrypt your compressed file"
    exit 1
fi

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}4/6: sha512sum is creating hash file '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.enc.SHA512SUM${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! sha512sum -b "$backupfile.xz.enc" > "$backupfile.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"
then
    echo "sha512sum failed to compute hashsum file"
    exit 1
fi

sha512sum -c "$backupfile.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}5/6: Decrypting your '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.enc${bold_yellow}' into a temporary file '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.dec${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! pv -W "$backupfile.xz.enc" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "$backupfile.xz.dec" -d -pass file:/home/vlastimil/.blablablabla 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "OpenSSL failed to decrypt your encrypted file"
    exit 1
fi

echo
echo "${bold_yellow}6/6: Comparing your un-encrypted, compressed, archived, directory file '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz${bold_yellow}' with a temporary file '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.dec${bold_yellow}'${nocolor}"
echo

if ! cmp "$backupfile.xz" "$backupfile.xz.dec"
then
    echo "Failed to compare files"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Your directory '${bold_red}$dir${nocolor}' has been successfully stored as '${bold_red}$backupfile.xz.enc${nocolor}'"
    rm "$backupfile.xz.dec"
    rm "$backupfile.xz"
    rm "$backupfile"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fine script. Even [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/#) doesn't find anything in it. Well done!

I only have minor comments.

You can safely omit the `sha512sum -c`.
It would only fail if the previous command failed.
For the rest, I cannot say it's complete paranoia.

The password file used with `openssl` commands is buried in the script and repeated twice.
It would be better to put that value in a variable and define at the top of the file.

A helper function would be more convenient to print the headers for the steps, instead of blocks of `echo`s.

> before I take another step and restructure it with `printf` and better error reporting, structure, exit codes, etc. I would like you to have a look first

I don't see what benefits `printf` will bring,
and the error reporting, structure, exit codes look just fine.

I would rename `bold_red` and `bold_yellow` to be more about the purpose than presentation.
Like `<em>` in HTML is for emphasis,
and `<strong>` for strong emphasis,
And the stylesheet (in this case the actual value of the variables) define the presentation, nicely segregated from the code.

Answer (score 1):

*Self-review for the follow-up question, which I will post in the following days.*

## Treat unset variables as an error when substituting

Add this to the beginning of the script:

```
set -o nounset
```

## `[ "$#" -eq 0 ]` instead of `[ -z "$1" ]`

It seems testing number of arguments is a better approach than testing if the first argument is set. Also, I added:

```
[ "$#" -gt 1 ] && echo "Multiple arguments are not supported!" && exit 1
```

for an obvious reason.

## As pointed out by Janos, put password file path into variable

And put it in the beginning of the script (maybe with a comment).

```
# In order to compress many directories with the same password,
# I decided to create a password file to avoid too many annoying prompts
passwd_file="/home/vlastimil/.blablablabla"
```

## Test for the existence of the password file

It may happen that you migrate to a different platform and / or accidentally delete the file.

```
[ ! -f "$passwd_file" ] && echo "The password file does not exist!" && exit 1
```

## You should also test for existence of the processed files

Like this, the comments are optional:

```
# TAR is archiving the directory into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}" ] && echo "File ${backup_file} exists, exiting." && exit 1

# XZ is compressing the archive into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz exists, exiting." && exit 1

# OpenSSL is decrypting the file (for verification) into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.dec" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.dec exists, exiting." && exit 1

# OpenSSL is encrypting the compressed file into the following permanent file,
# this is the result of successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.enc" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.enc exists, exiting." && exit 1

# SHA512SUM is computing a hash sum of the encrypted file into the following permanent file,
# this is the result of successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM exists, exiting." && exit 1
```

## Define all common colors (optional)

It happens one might like a change and / or later wants to re-define the styling. So this may be good idea, just comment out the colors that you don't use.

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
```

## As pointed out by Janos, color definitions should be renamed

> I would rename bold_red and bold_yellow to be more about the purpose than presentation.

And I agree:

```
action_number_color="${bold}${red}"
action_color="${bold}${yellow}"
file_color="${bold}${white}"
success_color="${bold}${green}"
```

## Again, as pointed out by Janos, there should be a helper printing function

> A helper function would be more convenient to print the headers for the steps, instead of blocks of `echo`s.

Like this, I added some leading and trailing coloring:

```
print_action()
{
    echo
    echo "${action_number_color}$1${no_color}"
    echo
}
```

## There could be a helper error function too

For instance:

```
print_error()
{
    echo
    echo "$1"
    exit 1
}
```

## There are too long lines of strings

Both in the code, and in the output. It could be simplified for example:

```
print_action "1/7:${action_color}
    TAR is archiving the directory
    ${file_color}${dir}${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}"
```

## `tar --verify` for enhanced integrity

The man page says:

> -W, --verify: attempt to verify the archive after writing it

Just to note: I take it, this option is only usable when creating the archive, and not if later checking the integrity.

## `if`s can be completely pulled out of the whole script

More importantly, it makes the script more readable this way:

```
tar --create --file="${backup_file}" "$1" --totals --verify ||

print_error "TAR failed to archive the directory!"
```

## Too long lines of code could be split

There were also places where the code itself could be formatted in two lines simply with the already present `|` (pipe), which acts as delimiter too.

```
pv --progress --timer --eta --rate --average-rate --bytes "${backup_file}.xz" |
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "${backup_file}.xz.enc" -pass file:"$passwd_file" 2> /dev/null ||

print_error "OpenSSL failed to encrypt the compressed file!"
```

## Average rate could further be added to the `pv` statement

As shown above, this could be somewhat useful to me at least if the file is very large.

## Remove `-W` parameter from `pv`

The `--wait` parameter is useless in case like this, where we are not waiting for user input. What's more, it caused `pv` not to output anything on small files.

## As pointed out by Janos, remove the `sha512sum --check`

Not only it is useless in this case, but it takes a few seconds. Better yet, you could replace it with showing the SHA-512 hash sum like this:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"
```

## Use `cmp` with `--silent` parameter

As you are not interested in actual differences in those files, and only wish to check the return value of `cmp`, this is the right way:

```
cmp --silent "${backup_file}.xz" "${backup_file}.xz.dec" &&

echo "Files are identical." ||

print_error "Failed to compare files!"
```

## Re-write awkward texts

I have re-written most of them, but one example:

> Comparing your un-encrypted, compressed, archived, directory file

could sound better as

> CMP is comparing the un-encrypted compressed file

## Current code looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# Treat unset variables as an error when substituting
set -o nounset

[ "$#" -eq 0 ] && echo "You need to give me one directory!" && exit 1
[ "$#" -gt 1 ] && echo "Multiple arguments are not supported!" && exit 1
[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "This is not a directory!" && exit 1
[ ! -w "$PWD" ] && echo "The current directory is not writable by you!" && exit 1

# In order to compress many directories with the same password,
# I decided to create a password file to avoid too many annoying prompts
passwd_file="/home/vlastimil/.blablablabla"

[ ! -f "$passwd_file" ] && echo "The password file does not exist!" && exit 1

dir=$(basename "$1")
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

backup_dir="${dir}_${today}"
# backup_dir="${dir}"

backup_file="${backup_dir}.tar"

# TAR is archiving the directory into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}" ] && echo "File ${backup_file} exists, exiting." && exit 1

# XZ is compressing the archive into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz exists, exiting." && exit 1

# OpenSSL is decrypting the file (for verification) into the following temporary file,
# it gets deleted on successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.dec" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.dec exists, exiting." && exit 1

# OpenSSL is encrypting the compressed file into the following permanent file,
# this is the result of successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.enc" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.enc exists, exiting." && exit 1

# SHA512SUM is computing a hash sum of the encrypted file into the following permanent file,
# this is the result of successful processing
[ -f "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM" ] && echo "File ${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM exists, exiting." && exit 1

bold=$(tput bold)
no_color=$(tput sgr0)

red=$(tput setaf 1)
#blue=$(tput setaf 4)
#cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
#magenta=$(tput setaf 5)

action_number_color="${bold}${red}"
action_color="${bold}${yellow}"
file_color="${bold}${white}"
success_color="${bold}${green}"

print_action()
{
    echo
    echo "${action_number_color}$1${no_color}"
    echo
}

print_error()
{
    echo
    echo "$1"
    exit 1
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "1/7:${action_color}
    TAR is archiving the directory
    ${file_color}${dir}${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}"

tar --create --file="${backup_file}" "$1" --totals --verify ||

print_error "TAR failed to archive the directory!"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "2/7:${action_color}
    XZ is compressing the archive
    ${file_color}${backup_file}${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz"

xz --format=xz --check=sha256 -9 --threads=8 --keep --verbose --extreme "${backup_file}" ||

print_error "XZ failed to compress the backup file!"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "3/7:${action_color}
    OpenSSL is encrypting the compressed file
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.enc"

pv --progress --timer --eta --rate --average-rate --bytes "${backup_file}.xz" |
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "${backup_file}.xz.enc" -pass file:"$passwd_file" 2> /dev/null ||

print_error "OpenSSL failed to encrypt the compressed file!"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "4/7:${action_color}
    SHA512SUM is computing a hash sum of the encrypted file
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.enc${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"

sha512sum --binary "${backup_file}.xz.enc" > "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM" ||

print_error "SHA512SUM failed to compute the hash sum!"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

awk '{ print $1 }' "${backup_file}.xz.enc.SHA512SUM"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "5/7:${action_color}
    OpenSSL is decrypting the file (for verification)
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.enc${action_color}
    into
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.dec"

pv --progress --timer --eta --rate --average-rate --bytes "${backup_file}.xz.enc" |
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "${backup_file}.xz.dec" -d -pass file:"$passwd_file" 2> /dev/null ||

print_error "OpenSSL failed to decrypt the encrypted file!"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_action "6/7:${action_color}
    CMP is comparing the un-encrypted compressed file
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz${action_color}
    with
    ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.dec"

cmp --silent "${backup_file}.xz" "${backup_file}.xz.dec" &&

echo "Files are identical." ||

print_error "Failed to compare files!" &&

{

print_action "7/7:${action_color}
    Cleaning up"

rm "${backup_file}" &&
echo "${backup_file} removed"

rm "${backup_file}.xz" &&
echo "${backup_file}.xz removed"

rm "${backup_file}.xz.dec" &&
echo "${backup_file}.xz.dec removed"

echo
echo "${success_color}Your directory ${file_color}${dir}${success_color} has been successfully stored as ${file_color}${backup_file}.xz.enc${no_color}"

exit 0

}
```

## And how it appears in Cygwin

[image: backupdir script output look in Cygwin]